# curl + Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: linux, bash, curl, networking, wget

I am using the following `bash` script in order to get info from curl from --> `https://komat/api/v1/jedh`  ( from chrome browser page we get the expected results but not from `curl` )

```
#!/bin/bash
url="https://komat/api/v1/jedh"
user="toto"
password="blomatis!"
curl_opts=(
    --insecure
    --request GET
    --header "Accept: application/json"
    --header "Content-Type: application/json"
    --header "Authorization: Basic $( echo "$user:$password" | base64 )"
)

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" "$url"
```

but the output that we get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;}
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

from the windows machine on the browser page we get **the right output** but not from the Linux machine by curl

any suggestion on how to resolve the above problem?

our machine version

```
more /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

Comment: Is this url https://komat/api/v1/jedh accessible? I can't reach it. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: yes its accessible? , but not from outside ( its internal )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake just here:

```
 echo "$user:$password" | base64
```

When you try to encode this string, you encode the string with the newline.

Just add `-n` parameter for `echo` command:

```
 echo -n "$user:$password" | base64
```

Comment: not help , we are with the same results

Comment: try to use google chrome console, for comparing encoded data: `encodedData = window.btoa('YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_PASSWORD')` with output of `echo -n "$user:$password" | base64` in console. Are they the same on both sides?

Comment: try just copying the output of `echo -n "$user:$password" | base64` directly to the `curl` command (without using a script). If it works, you can move on. And check username and password: are they correct?

Comment: no diff the same results

Comment: Did you try something like this? `curl --insecure --header "Authorization: Basic dG90bzpibG9tYXRpcyE=" https://komat/api/v1/jedh`. (used user:pass from your question)